# how do i count the rest of the films in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to count for kids films and the not so kids films. This is what I know 
so far.

this is for showing the table of which is yes and no and yes is for kids films for PG and G

```
select 
    category.name,film.title,film.rating,
    if(
        category.name='For_Kids' 
        or film.rating='PG' 
        or film.rating='G' ,"YES","NO" 
    ) 'rating yes or no' 
from
    film 
    inner join film_category on film.film_id = film_category.film_id 
    inner join
    category on film_category.category_id =category.category_id 
order by film.title asc;
```

I'm trying to count for kids films but I'm stuck on counting the other films besides kids. This is what I know so far.

```
select 
    sum(if(film.rating='G'or film.rating='PG',1,0)) as totalkidsfilms 
from
    film 
    inner join film_category on film.film_id = film_category.film_id
    inner join category on film_category.category_id =category.category_id
order by film.title asc;
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I would create a view using the first SELECT statement, but also including the film_id (to ensure everything is covered uniquely), and then do the counting via a select on your view with GROUP BY on the 'rating yes or no' field. At the moment you have the kid's film logic expressed twice, which offends my tidy mind and is not very maintainable, and you'd have to put it in again (backwards) to get the non-kid's film total: sum(if(film.rating='G'or film.rating='PG',0,1)). So don't do it like that, use a nice clean view and a GROUP BY.